# Git clone not functioning

Tags: git

I've been trying to configure my nvim (in linux os) recently.
Then suddenly the plugins didnt get installed (failed at cloning) and thought it might be plugin manager ([packer](https://github.com/wbthomason/packer.nvim)) problem, So was trying to reinstall it and now when I enter

```
$ git clone --depth 1 https://github.com/wbthomason/packer.nvim\
 ~/.local/share/nvim/site/pack/packer/start/packer.nvim
```

it just takes forever and then shows

```
 fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/wbthomason/packer.nvim/': SSL connection timeout
```

Comment: Works fine here. Probably be a network problem.

Comment: Can you access GitHub from your browser? Looks like a network (or firewall) issue

Comment: @knittl I can access it without any proxy/ vpn. Could be a network problem cause there's a lot of network filtering here but I can't tell for sure

Comment: So.. is there any alternatives ways that I could setup my editor?

Comment: @geater talk to your network administrators to fix their rules, they are obviously broken